# WatchConnectivity file transfer not working

Tags: ios, watchos-2

I am using WatchConnectivity to transfer an image from iOS to Watch OS. When debugging in simulator I am facing a problem

The file is transferred successfully as I can see in (sender side i.e. iOS)

```
public func session(session: WCSession, didFinishFileTransfer fileTransfer: WCSessionFileTransfer, error: NSError?)
```

Now from XCode I stop iOS simulator, change target to Watch App, Ctrl+Run Watch App (just run, no build).The below method is called.

```
public func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveFile file: WCSessionFile)
```

At last I do

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtURL(file.fileURL, toURL: destinationFileURL)
```

This call throws because there is no file at file.fileURL (which I checked in my MAC also).

The file.fileURL.path! is like this

```
/Users/<user name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DAD8E150-BAA7-43E0-BBDD-58FB0AA74E80/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/2CB3D46B-DDB5-480C-ACF4-E529EFBA2657/Documents/Inbox/com.apple.watchconnectivity/979DC929-E1BA-4C24-8140-462EC0B0655C/Files/EC57EBB8-827E-487E-8F5A-A07BE80B3269/image
```

Any clues?

- In actual I am transferring 15-20 images in loop.
- Sometime when not debugging I noticed that few image (not all) show
  up in watch simulator (also in actual watch). I have no idea what is
  happening with WC.
- No problem in transferring user info dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem. I was dispatching some code to main thread and the file move code was also inside that. WC framework clean up the file just after this method ends so the file must be moved before this function returns. I moved that code outside performInMainThread block and everything is working like charm.

```
public func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveFile file: WCSessionFile) 
{
   // Move file here
   performInMainThread { () -> Void in
         // Not here   
   }
}
```

Comment: Had the same issue, because at first after receiving file xCode complained about me updating table not in main queue and then after I moved code to it, got error saying "can't find file". Thanks a bunch for pointing this out!

Answer (score -2):

As the Apple documentation of [WCSessionDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSessionDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WCSessionDelegate/session:didReceiveFile:) Reference says regarding

**- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveFile:(WCSessionFile *)file**

when getting back the (WCSessionFile *)file parameter:

> The object containing the URL of the file and any additional
>   information. If you want to keep the file referenced by this
>   parameter, you must move it synchronously to a new location during
>   your implementation of this method. If you do not move the file, the
>   system deletes it after this method returns.

So the best to move it ASAP to a new location. It's safe as the system keeps the reference and doesn't delete it during the move.

```
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveFile:(WCSessionFile *)file {

    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *cacheDir = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Caches"];
    NSURL *cacheDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:cacheDir];

    if ([fileManager moveItemAtURL: file.fileURL toURL:cacheDirURL error: &error]) {

       //Store reference to the new URL or do whatever you'd like to do with the file
       NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:cacheDirURL];

    }

    else {

       //Handle the error
    }

}
```

WARNING! You have to be careful with the thread handling as delegates of WCSession run in the background queue so you have to switch to main queue if you'd like to work with UI.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work because you are returning from the method before reading the file (at which point the system can delete the file at any point). In addition you are assuming the file is small and can fit in memory without the app getting jetsammed, which is not going to always be the case. Finally, you are basically creating a copy of the file, which is more work than a filesystem move would be.

Comment: It's guaranteed as this version works in real app always, but the other sometimes yes sometimes no. Try it.